# Copy multiple html files with webpack2 (from src to dist folder)

Tags: html, copy-paste, webpack-2

Which loader/plugin should I use to move multiple html files from one folder (src) to another (dist) which only imports files that obey certain rules in this example I need to import multiple html files, so the regex would be:

> /.html$/

I know that I can move html using html-webpack-plugin but I don't want to create object instance for every page I want to move. I also don't want to make multiple imports in my app.js (entry point for webpack).

So i tried with copy-webpack-plugin but this one moves everything from src to dist. Is it possible to filter with my regex pattern or do you know other way that works to do this?

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ 
    from: './src',
    to: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
}],
```

I gues that I could use system

```
mkdir dist && cp ./src/*.html ./dist
```

And simply run this in my package.json in the script before running webpack -d
but this is not the "polite" way of doing this. I'm sure that webpack can do that easily..

Ps. Also, it would be nice to minimize those files, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

## Moving all files in batch

So for now it works like this. To not have to include every single file from the src folder in to my app.js (which is my entry point for webpack) I required all files using require.context()

Because my app.js is also in my src folder I use relative path to require all other file:

```
// requires all files in current directory and sub directories
require.context("./", true, /^\.\/.*\..*/);
```

Or if you want to import files with certain extension sue this instead:

```
// requires all html files in current directory and sub directories
require.context("./", true, /^\.\/.*\.html/);
```

So now everything is imported and I don't have to require files manually. The only thing I have to do is set entry to app.js using path.resolve.

I now can use test property to get what I want from within in webpack.config.js module rules.

```
 ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use:
          [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                context: './src',
                outputPath: '/',
                publicPath: '/'
              }
            },
            ...
```

This works fine my files are moved (but not minified). Perhaps someone can take this a little bit further and the answer will be completed.

Below i place full file for reference only

**webpack.config.js**

```
// imports node plugin which allows us to save data to a file for example css external files
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
// cleans defined folders before webpack will build new files now we can remove package.json commands "rm -rf ./dist && ..."
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
// copies to memory html from template file and injects css and javascript as well as img src to newly generated html file. 
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
// to include jquery we need to import 'jquery' in app.js but also we need to make connection between bundle.js jquery script
var Webpack = require('webpack');
// includes node path resover that is need for webpack-dev-server to run properly
var path = require('path');

// webpack configuration 
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "src/app.js"),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // defins the main utput directory
    filename: 'js/bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    port: 8080,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use:
          [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                context: './src',
                outputPath: '/',
                publicPath: '/'
              }
            }, 

          ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'img/',
            publicPath: '/' // this path relates to reference path from the index.html file that imports out bundle.js file
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test:  /\.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['es2015']
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src/sass")
        ],
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          //resolve-url-loader may be chained before sass-loader if necessary
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                minimize: false,
                sourceMap: true,
              }
            },
            'sass-loader'
          ]
        })
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // mapping jQuery variable to our node module dependency (remember to import 'jquery' in app.js)
    // below we make jquery available as both the $ and jQuery variable
    new Webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    }),
    // use extract plugin to build an external file loded by sass-loader > complied to css > movig to bundle.css
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'css/bundle.css'
    }),
    // remove all files from this folder before generating new files
    // new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use copy-webpack-plugin's support for globs to achieve what you want.

```
 new CopyWebpackPlugin([
   {
    from: './src/*.html',
    to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
])
```

The globs accept [minimatch options](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) too.

EDIT:

In addition, if you're copying just HTML (and want to minify them), you might want to take a look at [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin). The `minify` option allows you to minify those HTML files.

Comment: I think I have tried everything. file-loader, html-loader, extract-text-webpack-plugin numerus combinations. I menage to move only html files using file-loader but then I tried to make it work with html-loader (so i can minimize those files). And it almost work with that litle problem that all minimized files where prepend with [export.module=" .... here minified html...."]. Yet not fully sysfied from the end result. Its liek it was saved as js file with html extension,

Comment: I had problem in applying minimatch perhaps I did something wrong. I will post my findings without minification as a new answer to the question.